# Why use 'a' instead of 'an' before 'intellectual'?

Tags: articles

The 'i' is silent. Using 'a' to me does not sound awkward. I have seen it go both ways in style books. So what is correct? *An intellectual* or *a introvert*?

Comment: Is the `i` silent?

Comment: "an" for both, and the "i" is not silent, at least the way I speak English, it isn't.

Comment: If you are assuming that the ***n*** is pronounced *en* (or even *in* in some dialects) and that’s why the *I* seems to be silent that would not be the right way to think about it.  Otherwise how would you pronounce *net*? *enet*?  And even given that, ***an*** is used in front of words that start with a vowel *sound* not a vowel letter so it would take ***an***,either way. I’d be skeptical of any style guide that says *intellectual* takes ***a***.

Comment: ‘Ntellectual’ is utterly unpronounceable in English.

Answer (score 1):

The *i* in **intelligent** is not silent. The phonetic spelling, from [dictionary.com](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/intellectual?s=t), is

> in-tl-ek-choo-uh l

Notice how it starts with *i* and compare it with a word such as **[one](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/one?s=t)** in which the *o* is not heavily pronounced,

> wuhn

You would normally use **an** before words that sound like they start with a vowel and **a** before words that sound like they start with a consonant.

> An intellectual
>
> An introvert
>
> A one
>
> A euro
>
> A university

More on this at [englishpage](http://www.englishpage.com/articles/a-vs-an.htm).

Comment: @Jim good catch. I thought OP already knew the rule and was just confused about the pronunciation of the vowel in the word.